# Evaluation of the following integral

Tags: integration

How do I evaluate the following integral?

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh(a)k\ dk}{\cosh(k) + \cosh(a)}, \qquad a \geq0$$

Comment: Please share us your thoughts, what did you try, and where you are stuck, so that we will be able to help you .

Comment: Being an experimental physicist it is very difficult to solve such complicated integral, so honestly i did not tried. It appears as a part of my research work, so unless i found its answer i can not proceed further. Hence i seek help of mathematician.

Comment: @op how about a numerical approach? Just as good with the exception its more expensive in terms of computation. I have not checked your integral but it should converge nicely so you can truncate the upper limit.

Comment: $I=\dfrac{\pi^2}6+\dfrac{a^2}2+2~\text{Li}_2\Big(-e^{-a}\Big).\quad$ See [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function) and [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) for more information.

Comment: This question is being voted on to be closed. Please add some thoughts or context to make this question acceptable. It's a shame as it is an interesting question.

Comment: OP do you not have any CAS methods of solving this yourself?

Comment: To all who intend to vote to close: we have many people posting difficult integrals/sums on M.SE.  These are clearly not homework and asking for "effort" may be fruitless.  The statement of the problem itself in this case is enough to make for a good question.  Thus, please do not close.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve such an integral. I do however have access to Mathematica which does. I am including this as an answer so you at least have something to continue your research work off, unless you require the method.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(a)k}{\cosh(k)+cosh(a)}\,\mathrm{d}k \\
&= \operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-a})-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^a\right),\quad e^a\geq 0\land e^{-a}\geq-1
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying the identity $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac1z\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac12\ln^2(-z)$ simplifies the answer to:

$$
\frac{\pi^2}6+\frac{a^2}2+2\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{-a})
$$

(Which I realised after looking at Lucian's comment)

Comment: this is not too difficult to show, a substitution $e^k=x$ will bring this very close to a point where it is obvious that result should look like this :)